# Conditional statements order of precedence

Tags: python, python-3.x

Firstly, I am a beginner in python. So i won't be able to understand complex stuff.

So I tried to make an age testing thing (it was for testing before I try to make a large one). I wrote a code where if the age is equal to 4, then it shows "yes". and if the age in range of 2 to 8, it will show "what". and if it is some thing else, it shows "wot". i want the priority of the first statement more than the second one, like if the first one is true, then skip the second one.

code:

```
if (age<8 and age>2):
    print ("what")
if (a == 4):
    print ("yes")
else:
    print ("wot")
```

Comment: Replace the second `if` with `elif`.

Comment: What's the question? What is `a`? A typo?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
if age == 4 :
    print('yes')
elif age < 8 and age > 2 :
    print('what')
else : 
    print('wot')
```

python does not require round bracket in conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [elif](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) statement

```
if age == 4:
    print('yes')
elif age > 2 and age <8:
    print('what')
else:
    print('wot')
```

All these three statements are exclusive, i.e. only one print call will be made, the one that gets a True evaluation first from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The precedence goes like this:

`if` then `elif` then `else`. Usually you would have one `if` and as many `elif`s you want and one or no `else` statements. In your case, you would like to have a `if` statement to check for `age == 4` and `elif age > 2 and age < 8` while `else` takes care of any other possible case.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you should do:

```
if age == 4:
  print('yes')
elif age < 8 and age > 2: 
  print('what')
else:
  print('wot')
```

Then if the first conditional statement is true, the rest of the lines get skipped. If the first line fails, then it moves on to the second statement, etc...
Also, you used `age` as well as `a` for your age variable, that will also cause an issue.

Answer (score 0):

As what the others have replied, you would be using an nested if condition in your case. In python, your first condition will start as if, followed by elif (it stands for else if) and else (which concludes what will happen if none of the previous conditions are met)

For example:

if condition 1:
print("hi")

elif condition 2:
print("bye")

else:
print("hello")

Note that in python, once the first condition is met, it will automatically perform the action specified under that particular condition and exit from the if statement (meaning the rest of the statement will be ignored).